# Node.js - I want to get hash in app.js

Tags: node.js

**app.js**

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('userfile'), function(req, res){

  res.cookie('filename', req.file.originalname);
  res.cookie('filesize', req.file.size);
  var filename = __dirname +'/'+ req.file.path;
  console.log(hash(filename))

  res.cookie('hash', hash(filename));
  res.redirect('/hash')

})
```

**hash.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var algorithm = 'sha256';

module.exports = function(filename){
  var shasum = crypto.createHash(algorithm);
  var s = fs.ReadStream(filename);

  s.on('data', function(data) {
    shasum.update(data)
  })
  var hash;
  s.on('end', function() {
    hash = shasum.digest('hex') // this hash, i want to get in app.js 
  })
}
```

I have this two codes.

In hash.js, i want to get 'var hash' in app.js

How can i do it? I don't know what to do.

I need your helps.

Comment: What question are you asking, exactly? Because I have read this question multiple times now and still don't understand what you want to know

Comment: umm i want to use 'hash' in hash.js to app.js

Answer (score 0):

hash.js

```
module.exports = function(filename){
  var module = {};

  var shasum = crypto.createHash(algorithm);
  var s = fs.ReadStream(filename);

  s.on('data', function(data) {
    shasum.update(data)
  })
  s.on('end', function() {
    module.hash = shasum.digest('hex') // this hash, i want to get in app.js 
  })
  return module
}
```

app.js

```
var hash_module = require("./hash.js")(filename);
console.log(hash_module.hash)
```

Comment: i do it this but, hash_module.hash has undefined.

Comment: Is hash.js in the same directory as app.js?

Comment: no hash.js is in the 'routes' folder. so i changed 'var hash_module = require("./routes/hash.js")(filename);' but same..

Comment: and in hash.js i do console.log(module.hash); out of s.on('end'). it has undefined